# Changing the nature of click in daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I use [date range picker for bootstrap](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker)

Currently, if i use a range picker, two calenders are shown: one for "from-date" and one is for "to-date". And according to our user interface test results, users are expecting that when they click on a date in "from-date" calendar, they choose only the from-date. The same is valid for the other one.

However, "first-click" is for "from date" and second click is for "to-date" in the calendar.

What i want to realize can be found on [this link](http://luisfarzati.github.io/ng-bs-daterangepicker/). (No to ones who says "use then this")

So, is there any work around or a normal way to modify the nature of selecting dates?

Comment: Why don't you want to *use this* then?

Comment: its forked from daterangepicker project with less people and nothing is changed since more than 1 year.